# Flutter Provider reinitialize model

Tags: flutter, provider

I use MultiProvider and then create all my models. Lazy loading is enabled and as such when I open my page widget the constructor of my model is called when I call **Provider.of<>(context)**.

This initialize my model and the model gets fresh data.

I have the following issue however, when I pop the view(widget) and revisit the view(widget) later, **Provider.of<>(context)** is called again, but since the model was already initialized I get the previous data from the model (This is useful because I do use this to preserve state between certain screens).

I need my model to reinitialize since I need to refresh my data and reset the page values, and since the constructor is never called again, I don't get any of these.

No matter what I do, if I call the initialize method from **initState()** / **didChangeDependencies()** it always error since I'm changing the data while the widget is building.

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
MyChangeNotifier variable = MyChangeNotifier();

ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: variable,
  child: child()
)
```

To reinitialize my class, but from what I read this is bad and don't know where to call it.

I have no idea how to proceed and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what I was looking for in the Provider actual documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

The key is to call your code that would update the UI or trigger a rebuild inside a Future.microTask(). This will only then trigger the rebuild once the future completes and not trigger the rebuild while the widget tree is still building.

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(() =>
    context.read<MyNotifier>(context).getMyData(); // Or in my situation initialize the page.
  );
}
```