# Flutter provider values reset after closing the dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I've created a ChangeNotifier and added it to the main.dart providers list like below:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
    create: (context) => AppState(),
);
```

and I have a dialog which I wrap in `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` to have access to the provider inside dialog, like below:

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: AppState(),
        child: LanguageDialog(),
      );
    });
});
```

but the problem is that when I set some data in the provider state inside the dialog it works fine as long as I'm inside the dialog! when I close the dialog the state resets! and I have no idea why this happens.
Also I've tried setting some state in another route and the result was that the state's data in that route was not the same as the dialog.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check this answer. It might help you with your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335229/16407621

Answer (score 1):

ChangeNotifierProvider.value creates a new AppState instance and passes to your dialog. It's not same as your global AppState instance. Instead of creating a new provider for your dialog you can access to Provider using `Provider.of` function inside your dialog.

```dart
var appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
```

You can either access to provider inside `LanguageDialog` or pass it through argument like this:

```dart
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return LanguageDialog(
        appState: Provider.of<AppState>(context);
      );
    }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
But I've tried using `Provider.of` inside the dialog but I always get the error that it couldn't find the provider above this widget, I also tried your second solution to pass the provider instance to the widget and it worked but there was one problem that the data was not updating inside the widget, what can I do about that?

Comment: @Komeyl94 probably there's an issue on your provider model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335229/16407621

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the provider is scoped to the same routes and since you are navigating to a new route via dialog box, provider will not store the value when you exit that DialogBox.

Make sure to create your provider above the MaterialApp so that the provider is scoped to the entire app. You can specify it like this :-

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
    create: (context) => AppState(),
    child: MaterialApp(
       home: HomeScreen())
);
```