# Flutter - how to call a method on all providers?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using the Provider package with my Flutter app. When the user signs out I would like to reset all the providers to avoid stale data upon the next sign in.

Currently the only way I know to access providers is via `Provider.of<T>()` which I will have to call once per provider. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all state, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777054/3925977) from the provider creator himself.