# Flutter: How to reset provider view model data?

Tags: flutter, provider

Is there any way to reset all view model data (ChangeNotifier)?  Tried to dispose the view model but didn't work. I want to clear all data when user logout.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776375/clear-state-in-flutter-when-using-provider) help you? Basically adding an ObjectKey to your Provider which you change when the user logs out or whatever.