# Flutter - How to wipe provider data after user signed out from app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I am using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for state management in my flutter application. I have implemented provider using `Multiprovider`.

I want to wipe provider data when the user signed out from the app I have read out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777054/7527342) comment but don't understand it well.

Answer (score 1):

If you rebuild your `MultiProvider` widget with a different key, it reset the state, hence, rebuild the providers. That's what is explained there.

Hence, what you need to do in order to achieve it, is something like:

```
String userId = myUserId;

void signOut() {
   setState(() => userId = '');
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return MultiProvider(
    key: ObjectKey(userId),
    providers: // Your providers
    child: SomeSubtree(),
  );
}
```

Assuming you are using a `StatefulWidget`, in this case.
You can read more about how keys work in Flutter [here](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d).

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working. can you give a complete example?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when user A logout, and then user B login, the old data of user A still here.

To fix that problem I have 3 solutions:

1/. In every `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` for `update` prop, have to check state of login status, and return new `Provider`, otherwise return updated `Provider`

And on other Provider doesn't depend on login status, we have to manually call the function to clear data.

2/. Another solution is try to rebuild mainApp again when logout.
Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68572345/1122308

And it maybe does not work for some app because structure is different. **If you want it work for your app, please post your app's code. We can help you.**

3/. Restart OS level your app when logout by this package: https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app

It's ok but not good for UX. And iOS doesn't work https://github.com/gabrimatic/restart_app/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to clear the state when the user wants to logOut, mainly by setting the token to null

And also if you stored these user data in the device you should clear them. For me I use sharedprefrences.

example of my code

```
  Future<void> logOut() async {
    _token = null;
    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();
  }
```

if you stored other data also set it to null, and be sure to notifyListeners after setting these data to null.

I suppose that you did the multiprovder correctly, so I only get you the idea to do the LogOut

Comment: This does not reset the state of providers.

Comment: I think that you do not understand the provider so far. I wrote  `notifyListeners();` and this will pass the new value to the app. I said I assume that you did the multi-providers correctly Like you wrapped the app or the specific widget with `ChangeNotifierProvider` or `Consumer` to listen to those changes

Comment: As far as I know, your code only changes the value of providers but does not reset the state. I want to re-instantiate the providers after logout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code using [Miguel Ruivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6919963/miguel-ruivo) answer as basis assuming your logout code is inside one of the initial providers.

1. Make your main app stateful.
2. Pass in the `triggerRebuildMultiProvider()` as callback function to your authentication provider or anywhere where the logout code is.

main.dart

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final MyUtilityClass myUtilityClass = MyUtilityClass();

  // initial key for MultiProvider
  String _uniqueKey = '';

  // Method to trigger rebuild MultiProvider
  void triggerRebuildMultiProvider() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    int timestamp = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    setState(() {
      _uniqueKey = timestamp.toString();
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      key: ObjectKey(_uniqueKey),
      providers: [
        // pass in the trigger rebuild function as logout callback
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) =>
                AuthProvider(triggerRebuildMultiProvider)),
```

auth_provider.dart

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Function _triggerRebuildMultiProvider;

  AuthProvider(Function triggerRebuildMultiProvider)
      : _triggerRebuildMultiProvider = triggerRebuildMultiProvider,
        super();


  Future<void> logout() async {
    // your logout code

    // call trigger rebuild
    _triggerRebuildMultiProvider();
  }
```